# Reuse single tcp connection for multiple http requests

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, httprequest

I try to reuse a single tcp socket/connection to make multiple HTTP requests.
The problem is, that only the first request is performed and the second one not.

I know that `agent.createConnection` should create a underlying socket or return a stream.
For some reason i need to work there with streams and cant return a socket.
The tcp socket that is outside created should/must be reused.

For what i understand, as long as the socket is open and not closed from any party, it should be possible to make as many HTTP requests as needed.

`index.js`

```js
const { Agent } = require("http");
const request = require("./request");
const { createConnection } = require("net");
const { PassThrough, Duplex } = require("stream");

const agent = new Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

let readable = new PassThrough({
    //end: false
});
let writable = new PassThrough({
    //end: false
});

// example.com resolves to 93.184.216.3
let socket = createConnection({
    host: "93.184.216.34",
    port: 80
});

socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("tcp socket closed");
});

socket.on("end", () => {
    console.log("tcp socket ended");
});

socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

socket.pipe(readable, { end: false });
writable.pipe(socket, { end: false });

agent.createConnection = (options, cb) => {

    console.log(options.href)

    let stream = Duplex.from({
        readable,
        writable
    });

    // uncomenting this, let the app exit
    // the second request is not performed
    /*
    stream.setKeepAlive = (...args) => {
        console.log("stream.setKeepAlive", args);
        return socket.setKeepAlive(...args);
    };

    stream.unref = (...args) => {
        console.log("stream.unref called", args);
        return socket.unref(...args);
    };

    stream.setTimeout = (...args) => {
        console.log("stream.setTimeout called", args);
        return socket.setTimeout(...args);
    };
    */

    // this keep the app running, but no other request is performed
    // the app exists after a while (~2-5min) when "end" & "close" event are fired
    stream.setKeepAlive = socket.setKeepAlive;
    stream.unref = socket.unref;
    stream.setTimeout = socket.setTimeout;


    process.nextTick(() => {
        cb(null, stream);
    });

};



request("http://example.com/foo", {
    agent,
    headers: {
        "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || result);
});


request("http://example.com/bar", {
    agent,
    headers: {
        "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || result);
});
```

`request.js`

```js
const url = require("url");

/**
 * Does a http request
 * @param {*} uri 
 * @param {*} options 
 * @param {*} cb 
 * 
 * @ignore
 * 
 * @returns {http.ClientRequest} https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest
 */
function perform(uri, options, cb) {

    let { protocol } = new url.URL(uri);

    if (!["http:", "https:"].includes(protocol)) {
        throw new Error(`Unspported protocol "${protocol.slice(0, -1)}`);
    }

    // NOTE: Automaticly set keep alive header when agent is passed?
    if (options?.agent && !options?.setKeepAliveHeader) {
        options.setKeepAliveHeader = true;
    }

    if (options?.setKeepAliveHeader) {
        options.headers = {
            ...options?.headers,
            "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
        };
    }

    let request = require(protocol.slice(0, -1)).request(uri, options, (res) => {

        let chunks = [];

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("error", cb);

        res.on("end", () => {

            let body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

            if (res.headers["content-type"] && res.headers["content-type"].includes("application/json")) {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
            }

            cb(null, {
                headers: res.headers,
                status: res.statusCode,
                body
            });

        });

    });


    request.on("error", (err) => {
        cb(err);
    });


    if (options.callEnd) {
        request.end(options.body);
    }
    //request.write(options.body + "\r\n");

    return request;

}


/**
 *  @function request
 * Does a http/https request
 *
 * @param {String} uri 
 * @param {Object} options 
 * @param {Function} cb Callback

 * @returns {http.ClientRequest} https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest
 */
module.exports = function request(uri, options, cb) {

    if (!cb && options instanceof Function) {
        cb = options;
        options = {};
    }

    if (!cb) {
        cb = () => { };
    }

    options = Object.assign({
        method: "GET",
        body: "",
        followRedirects: true,
        callEnd: true,
        setKeepAliveHeader: true
    }, options);


    return perform(uri, options, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {

            cb(err);

        } else {

            if (options.followRedirects && result.status >= 300 && result.status < 400) {

                perform(result.headers.location, options, cb);

            } else {

                cb(null, result);

            }

        }
    });

};
```

How can i reuse the tcp socket for multiple requests?

---

Edit:

Thought i had a possible solution with the following snippet. Its basically to set the agent option `maxSockets` to `1` and override the `.destory` function for the returned stream/"socket" in `.createConnection`.

```js
const { Agent } = require("http");
const request = require("./request");
const { createConnection } = require("net");
const { PassThrough, Duplex } = require("stream");

const agent = new Agent({
    maxSockets: 1,
});


// example.com resolves to 93.184.216.3
let socket = createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 80
});

socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("tcp socket closed");
});

socket.on("end", () => {
    console.log("tcp socket ended");
});

socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});


agent.createConnection = ({ host, port }) => {

    console.log("Create connection to", `tcp://${host}:${port}`);

    let readable = new PassThrough({
        //end: false
    });

    let writable = new PassThrough({
        //end: false
    });

    let stream = Duplex.from({
        readable,
        writable
    });

    stream.once("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Agent stream error", err);
    });

    //stream.setKeepAlive = () => { console.log("setKeepAlive called"); };
    //stream.ref = () => { console.log("ref called") };
    //stream.unref = () => { console.log("unref called"); };
    //stream.setTimeout = () => { console.log("setTimeout called"); };

    stream.ref = socket.ref;
    stream.unref = socket.unref;
    stream.setKeepAlive = socket.setKeepAlive;
    stream.setTimeout = socket.setTimeout;



    stream.destroy = () => {
        console.log("stream destroey", `tcp://${host}:${port}`);
    };

    writable.pipe(socket);
    socket.pipe(readable);

    // calling the passed callback causes that every 
    // requests has the same result as first one that uses this agent
    // this has to be synchron, not sure why tho...
    return stream;

};


request("http://localhost:80/anything/foo", {
    agent,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        url: "http://localhost:80/anything/foo"
    }),
    headers: {
        "connection": "keep-alive",
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || "Done - http://example.com/foo:", result.body);
});

request("http://localhost:80/anything/bar", {
    agent,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        url: "http://localhost:80/anything/bar"
    }),
    headers: {
        "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || "Done - http://example.com/bar:", result.body);
});

request("http://localhost:80/anything/baz", {
    agent,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        url: "http://localhost:80/anything/baz"
    }),
    headers: {
        "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || "Done - http://example.com/baz:", result.body);
});
```

This works very well when all requests are invoked "immediately".
When a request is delayed, because its done based on other actions, e.g. HTTP request or just as simple `setTimeout`, the request is not performed because the underlying tcp socket is closed...

```js
setTimeout(() => {

    console.log("Timeout, fetch /baz")

    request("http://localhost:80/anything/baz", {
        agent,
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            url: "http://localhost:80/anything/baz"
        }),
        headers: {
            "connection": "keep-alive"
        }
    }, (err, result) => {
        console.log(err || "Done - http://example.com/baz:", result.body);
    });

}, 5000);
```

Agent & tcp socket are destroyed before the request is invoked.

Comment: You only need one http server and it issues a keep-alive in the header which the client recieves and the client will stay there until it times out because it never got a refresher keep-alive from the server.